# ASCII Upload from Windows 10 to mainframe adds strange characters to start of file

Tags: windows, ftp, zos

I've been doing Windows to z/OS mainframe FTPs for a long time and I've never encountered this situation before today and hope someone can help me out.

I have a group of files that I need to transfer to our mainframe, but when I do so, somehow the characters "o:?" are being added to only the first record in the files.

When I view the files in a text editor I do not see any other characters before the start of the first record.  All of the rest of the data looks fine.

The files are all in a fixed-format and I specify that they should be transferred in ASCII, so just the first record is out of whack once on the mainframe.

I've tried using both FTP from the Windows Command Prompt as well as FileZilla with the same result.

Unfortunately, because of tight security, I am not able to run mainframe JCL to "get" the file from my workstation and the 3270 emulator software I have to use (Mocha TN3270) does not have transfer capability.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file Utf-8 - if so it could be the Byte order mark: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Thank you, Bruce.  That was the problem.  When I saved the files without BOM in UltraEdit and then transferred to the mainframe, everything was transferred correctly.

Comment: I will put it up as the answer for future reference for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is **UTF-8** it could be the [Byte order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

The **Byte order Mark** is 3 bytes at of the beginning of the file and could be treated as normal text by the file transfer program.

Comment: the BOM is 3 bytes in UTF-8